# Word that means "of or relating to 'vocabulary'"

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

I'm looking for an adjective that would mean essentially the equivalent to the meaning some might ascribe to the made up word "vocabularic."  Is there a word that means "of or applying to vocabulary?"

For example: "I hope this utilitarian endowment proves itself by aiding in the construction of constructs and the eschewing of [vocabularic] obfuscation."

I realize this word is found in some dictionaries, such [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vocabularic), but I was wondering if a more general, scholarly, or accepted word is commonly used.

Comment: I think *the eschewing of vocabularic obfuscation* is a fabulous autological term!

Comment: @bib: That comment was the most obfuscated sarcasm I've ever read.

Comment: OED says adjectival ***vocabulary*** *(Of or pertaining to words; composed of, or concerned with, words)* is "rare". But they don't say that of ***vocabular*** *(Of, pertaining to, or concerning words)*. Sadly for @bib, they don't actually list ***vocabularic*** at all.

Comment: In the example you give I would simply use *verbal*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[lexical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lexical)**

> Relating to the words or vocabulary of a language <sub>(Oxford)</sub>

...*eschewing of lexical obfuscation*

Comment: I actually meant that the entire sentence I made as an example refers to a dictionary being given as a gift.

Comment: @brandaemon: See edit

Comment: @brandaemon- I’d think that such a gift would tend to encourage sesquipedalianism.

Comment: This answer most applies to vocabulary itself.

Answer (score 0):

dictional is the adjective form of diction, which means choice of words, especially with regard to correctness, clearness or effectiveness (Merriam Webster).

So...

We eschew dictional obfuscation.

Comment: I'm looking more for something that applies to words themselves rather than which words to use

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten example: "I hope this utilitarian endowment proves itself by aiding in the construction of constructs and the eschewing of **semantic** obfuscation."

Comment: Semantics has more to do with language and structure rather than words and definitions

Comment: @brandaemon I don't know why you say that, semantics specifically pertains to meaning. It should not be confused with "linguistic" or "syntactic".